# NA Values and Numeric Datatype

Tags: r

I'm currently using `read.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package to write data from an Excel spreadsheet to a data frame. My problem is that the data frame becomes type character because the first row read from the file has NA values. Converting the frame using `as.numeric` just screws up the formatting. So currently, I run a command like so:

```
CDF<- read.xlsx(wb, sheet=1, startRow=2,cols=c(2,3))
```

CDF then equals to a dataframe with the following values:

> 

```
    NA                     NA     
1 3.1569948515638899E-3  4.2560545366418102E-2                        
2 4.6179211819458499E-2  0.43699596110695599          
3 9.3875238651998996E-2  0.63041471352096301     
4 7.1254813513786902E-2  0.76236994294326599
```

That's fine. But I need to run the command beginning from row 1, not row 2. If I run  `CDF<- read.xlsx(wb, sheet=1, startRow=1,cols=c(2,3))` then the data frame I get is

```
  jobs.1000output.ratio     earn.output.ratio
1                      NA                    NA
2   3.1569948515638899E-3 4.2560545366418102E-2
3   4.6179211819458499E-2   0.43699596110695599
4   9.3875238651998996E-2   0.63041471352096301
5   7.1254813513786902E-2   0.76236994294326599
6   4.2305078854580701E-2   0.61710149253731295
```

But in this case the datatype of any value I choose from CDF is a `string`. I need it to be a `numeric` type. How can I keep the `NA` values in the data frame while still preserving the overall datatype of the frame? (I want to avoid using `as.numeric` because I want my data frame to keep being two columns)

Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: Can't you just use the `colClasses` option to specify the class of each column?

Comment: What is the problem with the use of as.numeric ? CDF[1] <- as.numeric(CDF[1]) ?

Comment: @NicoCoallier I didn't think about doing it that way lol. Thanks a lot! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
CDF <- read.xlsx(wb, sheet=1, startRow=1, cols=c(2,3), colClasses = "numeric")
```

Comment: that's an option for the csv package, not for the xlsx package 

Comment: The documentation says that it's an option. From `?read.xlsx` it says `read.xlsx(file, sheetIndex, sheetName=NULL, rowIndex=NULL,
  startRow=NULL, endRow=NULL, colIndex=NULL,
  as.data.frame=TRUE, header=TRUE, colClasses=NA,
  keepFormulas=FALSE, encoding="unknown", ...)`

Comment: it says "unused argument (colClasses="numeric"). Any idea why that is?

Comment: I can't replicate that error. When I specify the argument I get no complaints. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Right, so I figured out that I was using a different package. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

To follow on my comments I have create a function for you:

```
return_num <- function(dataframe){

    for(i in 1:ncol(dataframe)){

        if(!is.numeric(dataframe[,i])){

            dataframe[,i] = as.numeric(dataframe[,i])
}else{

print(paste(names(dataframe[i]), " is already numeric"))

}
}
}
```

Could call the function after

```
return_num(CDF)
```